# Can the upper incomplete gamma function be normalized to a probability distribution?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, gamma-function

The upper incomplete gamma function is defined as

$$\Gamma\left(s,x\right)=\int_{x}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$

Can this expression be normalized to obtain a distribution on $x$? i.e. does the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\Gamma\left(s,x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dtdx$$

converge? If so, to what? (i.e. what is the normalizing constant). Is this a special case of a known distribution?

Comment: See [gamma distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) CDF

Answer (score 0):

One can write the tail of a Gamma$(s,1)$-distributed variable $X$ in terms of the upper incomplete Gamma function $\Gamma(s,x)$:
$$\Bbb P(X>x)=\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_x^\infty t^{s-1}\,\mathrm e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\Gamma(s,x)}{\Gamma(s)}.$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^\infty\Gamma(s,x)\,\mathrm dx=\Gamma(s)\int_0^\infty\Bbb P(X>x)\,\mathrm dx=\Gamma(s)\,\Bbb E[X]=s\Gamma(s)=\Gamma(s+1).$$